# Why does jQuery on/keyup fire on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.account-password').on('input', function() {
    console.log(4)
    checkPassword();
});
```

Why does the above fire on page load? It's right underneath document ready and it's really annoying...
This also fires on page load:

```
.keyup(function() {
```

There is nothing clicking on that element as it's displayed none?? It also triggers when I press keys on my keyboard, but I am not inside the targetted input field???

Comment: Please edit the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: It shouldn’t: there is probably other code on your page (which you have not shared) that has this side effect

Comment: There is literally nothing more to it, it's just a html input which is displayed none. And there is no more JS apart from this inside a document ready

Comment: @Ads please show this. We cannot replicate what you see from just a description and the current code provided

Answer (score 0):

The issue was: Even though my form was displayed none. Browser pre-filled the form with saved password which triggered the event. I tried autocomplete="off" on the input but it still triggers. Anyone idea how to prevent browser from filling this in?